# Display featured image URL in the loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem trying to get the thumbnail URL of each post on the archive page. 
I used the basic technics but it always return the url of the first featured image of the page.

Here the part of the code of my template-parts/post/content/content.php

The goal of this is to open the featured image of each post on a lightbox.
Here the link to the page : http://leos-sipek.thomasdesnoyers.com/category/divers-types-dune-ideographie-stochastique/peinture-sur-papier/metaplasme/

If you click on the second post it shows the featured image of the first post.

```
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <a rel="lightbox" data-gall="gall-frame" data-lightbox-type="inline" href="#inline-content">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' ); ?>
        </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Lightbox -->

    <div id="inline-content" style="display:none;">
            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) : ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
            <div class="img-single" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')"></div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem is because youre not telling WordPress to show the image of the individual posts. Youre grabbing the ID of the first post and then just re-using it over and over for the subsequent posts. Nowhere in the code you posted does it show you updating the $post->ID.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't have any info about the ID in the loop, it doesn't show it in front. I thought it would took the id of each post as it's in the loop. I tried to use the same technique as fo taking the display the ID of the post :

Comment: <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I was pointing the same url for each lightbox so it opened the same each time.
I change the Href of each lightbox by the ID of each post and it works.

```
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <a rel="lightbox" data-gall="gall-frame" data-lightbox-type="inline" href="#<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' ); ?>
        </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Lightbox -->

    <div id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" style="display:none;">
            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) : ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); endif ?>
            <div class="img-single" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')"></div>
    </div>
```

Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

In your code you displaying only first element from $image array, try to change this line:

```
<div class="img-single" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')"></div>
```

via this code to run through all array elements:

```
<?php foreach ($image as $image_link) : ?>
<div class="img-single" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image_link; ?>')"></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is just one image per post so it would be enough normally ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [the_post_thumbnail_url()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail_url) ?

```
<div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a rel="lightbox" data-gall="gall-frame" data-lightbox-type="inline" href="#inline-content">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' ); ?>
    </a>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox -->

<div id="inline-content" style="display:none;">
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) : ?>

        <div class="img-single" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'single-post-thumbnail'); ?>')"></div>
</div>
```

However if you are only using one lightbox for all posts in a loop, you will need to set something like a `data-url="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'single-post-thumbnail'); ?>"` in the lightbox link. Then you can use JS to swap that URL in for the background image on click. Something like:

```
<script>
    (function($) {
        $('a[rel="lightbox"]').on('click', function(e) {
            var imgSrc = $(this).data('url');

            $('#inline-content').css('background-image', imgSrc);
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```